# Angular 8- if the first api call returns nothing Call a second api

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular8

I have to first call an API and if the value is empty array or null, I have to call second API and return the value from the second API. what is the best way to do this in angular.. I read about mergemap,concatmap,forkjoin etc and found switchmap to be more suitable. This is my method

```
 getContact(cdsid: string): Observable<any> {
    const body = JSON.stringify({ cdsid: cdsid });
    this._isLoading = true;
    const endpoint = environment.endpointContacts;
    const endpointUSA = environment.endpointContactUSA + '/get-user-info/' + cdsid;
    return this.http
      .post<any>(endpoint, body)
      .pipe(

        map(
          data => { return of(data[0]) }),

          switchMap(d => {

          return d.pipe(
            map(
              cData => {
         
                if (cData.contact.length > 0) {
                  
                  return cData.contact[0];
                } else {
                  
                  return this.http.get<any>(endpointUSA)                  
                  .pipe(
                     map(
                      data => { return data; }),
                    catchError(
                      (error) => {
                        this._isError = true;
                        return EMPTY;
                      }),
                    finalize(() => {                     
                      this._isError = false;
                    })
            
                  );

                }

              }
            )
          )

        }),

        catchError(
          (error) => {
            this._isError = true;
            return EMPTY;
          }),

        finalize(() => {
            this._isError = false;
        })

      );
  }
```

But the above method doesn't return data from the second API though the first one has an empty array coming as a result. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pipe looks a little bit messed up. Try the following:

```js
this.http.post<any>(endpoint, body).pipe(
  // Success response.
  // Use switchMap; because we're gonna return another Observable in case of error
  switchMap(data => {
     if(data == null || (Array.isArray(data) && data.length == 0) ) {
        return this.get<any>(endpointUSA)
     } else {
        // Success, everything went nice so rewrap data into an observable
        return of(data);
     }
  }),
  // Handle http errors? do you desire to call the second endpoint in case of http error? you can do it! or not, it's up to you
  catchError(error => this.http.get<any>(endpointUSA))   
);
```